# ROS Answers SE migration: Loading a map

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, map-server, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys I'm trying to load a map, but I'm getting the following error,

```
rosrun map_server map_server maps/map.yaml 

[ INFO] [1540147650.086107759]: Loading map from image "maps/map.pgm" Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my YAML file

```
image: /home/pradheep/cat_ws/src/simulation/maps/map.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-100.000000, -100.000000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306361/loading-a-map/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2018-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, found the solution in here https://answers.ros.org/question/303002/map_server-segfaults/

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2018-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0